# Image storing for ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, web

I'm developing a movie forum as my pet-project. The idea that I have Movie model which contains title, description and release year, but also I want store cover for the movie and other related photos. I'm new to ASP.NET platform and web-development so I actually don't know where to start. What is the most optimal technology to implement storing images feature and displaying them, which could be useful in for real production in future?

Now I'm using only PostgresSQL, but I know that storing images as bytes don't optimal solution. Also I saw solutions by using cloud storages, but I don't know what should I choose for my project.